# how do I create gradients that have intermediate color steps?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I was working with gradients through xml file.

the problem is while the gradient as such works fine, i want a stepped transition from one color to the other and not gradual.

There seems to be no option for stepped gradient.
What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

If you can/want to move to a programmatic solution, the API lets you create gradients with color steps, and define the relative (0.0-1.0) position for each color, with two arrays:

```
// this creates a semi-lucid cylinder gradient
int[] colGreen =  {Color.parseColor("#006600"),
           Color.parseColor("#01cc00"),
           Color.parseColor("#119911"),
           Color.parseColor("#22bb33"),
           Color.parseColor("#ddffdd"),
           Color.parseColor("#006600") };

float[] pos = {0.0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.55f, 0.85f, 1f};

LinearGradient gr = new LinearGradient(x0, y0, x1, y1, colGreen, pos, tilemode));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... However i dont want to use the linear gradient as the code already looks too clumsy. I was trying to use styles and created a seperate xml. Cant anything be done in that??

Comment: @Abhik I'm sorry, that I know, you can't specify gradient steps in xml.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a background layout that contains as many views as you need steps. Then set a different gradient for each view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/gradient1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/gradient2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient2" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```